# Is the fair market value of "pro bono" work tax deductible?

Tags: united-states, charity

If a person contributes a car, art, clothing, or other items of value to a charity, that person gets to deduct the fair market value of the contributed goods from their taxable income.

Suppose, instead, a lawyer did pro bono work for a recognized legal charity such as a law clinic or legal aid group directed at say, elderly people. Would the lawyer be able to deduct the value of the hours contributed (at the lawyer's hourly rate)?

Answer (score 2):

## No

[IRS Pub. 526](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p526.pdf), Table 1, lists "Value of your time or services" under "Not Deductible As Charitable Contributions".  This is repeated several other places in the document.

However, expenses incurred in the course of providing the services can be deductible in some cases.

There's more specific information for lawyers at https://practice.findlaw.com/practice-guide/tax-deductions-for-lawyers-providing-pro-bono-services.html.

Comment: Note that this isn't a reason to prefer donations over pro bono work.  A worker who donates their time will have the same after-deduction income as a worker who does extra paid work but donates the proceeds to charity.